# RDP with VPN connection: User account did not work

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

I am in a network using a VPN.
I want to connect a Windows 11 computer in this network using RDP.
When I try to connect to this computer using the RDP app for MacBooks it doesn't work.
Before connecting to the VPN I made a new firewall rule to allow ICMPv4, that's needed cause otherwise I cannot ping the other computer.

Now I have problems using RDP since I cannot connect to the computer. I have the hostname, user account, and password, but it says that the account did not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you disconnect the VPN , that is , does it support split tunnel?

Comment: tbf I don't know that much about VPNs and all that. One of my friends recommended using a VPN when I want to use my computer via RDP for security reasons and also because of other things I plan to do. So I just can tell u that I am using a Speedport Smart 3 router which uses WireGuard. Maybe this gives you an answer, if not u could tell me how I would find this info which I could then provide you @John

Comment: There are numerous kinds of VPN.  You would need to look at the VPN specs.  For example, Microsoft VPN does not natively support Split Tunnel. Other VPN have settings to enable Split Tunnel.

Comment: I just looked it up and apparently yes, Speedport Smart 3 should support split tunnel. @John

Comment: I will look around a bit. I am not sure why RDP stops with the tunnel connected.

Comment: thanks for your time @John

Comment: You might also ask Speedport.  I have used NCP Secure Entry IPsec VPN with Split Tunnel enabled and it happily supports RDP.  As noted I will look around a bit.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the user account. Since I just added another local account and with that it works...
What do I have to enter when I wanna use a Microsoft Account to connect? I have the email + password + the username on the machine + the pin to unlock the computer - but when entering the username or email with the password it doesn't work... @John

Comment: If you wish to use a Microsoft Account, you can log into Microsoft Live and reset the password if need be.

Comment: Actually no, I don't want to reset the password since I know that the password I have is correct. But maybe it is also not working because it's the admin account on this device?
The question now is, what do I enter where? Is the username now the hostname or the email address? and is the Password now the password of the MS account or the password/pin to unlock the local computer? Do you know this? @John

Comment: Microsoft Accounts can be unlocked by password, PIN, or Fingerprint if it has one.